# Echarts: Is there any way to add images to charts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, echarts

I'm using Echarts to create treemap.
[image]
I want to change the color of the tree to image.
Like this.
[image]

```
              itemStyle: {
            color: {
              image: require("./french.png"),
            },
          },
```

I tried to use itemStyle, but it doesn't work! Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the graphic component. It let's you add any graphic object to your chart with given coordinates.

[image]

Just check the documentation of this component to know how to use it. https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at one of their examples which uses images:

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=wind-barb

```
      {
        type: 'image',
        style: {
          image: api.value(dims.weatherIcon),
          x: -weatherIconSize / 2,
          y: -weatherIconSize / 2,
          width: weatherIconSize,
          height: weatherIconSize
        },
        position: [point[0], 110]
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add a unique image to each label within series data like this:

```
{
  "value": 23,
  "name": "Arizona",
  "path": "US/Arizona",
  label: {
    show: true,
    formatter: '{b}',
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    backgroundColor: {
      image: 'image1.jpg',
    },
  },
},
```